# Search command output for string minitest

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, minitest

I'm trying to create a minitest for chef (minitest::spec) and I'm a little lost at how to accomplish what I want in ruby.

What I want to do is have the code run the 'date' command and then check if the output contains 'UTC'.

I have this so far, but I don't know how to check the output for 'true':

```
it "uses the correct timezone" do
    timezone_check = shell_out("date")
    timezone_check.to_s.include?('UTC')
end
```

I tried to use .must_output, but I don't know how to incorporate it. Is this even the best way to accomplish what I want?

Any input is appreciated!

Thanks.

EDIT: I have now tried this:

```
  it "uses the correct timezone" do
    date_input = `date`
    proc { puts date_input.to_s }.must_output /UTC/
  end
```

but it results in this:

```
Failure:
test_0002_uses_the_correct_timezone(recipe::base::default) [/var/chef/minitest/base/default_test.rb:18]:
In stdout.
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
-/UTC/
+"Fri Apr 19 17:50:27 UTC 2013
+"
```

Comment: Take a look at the MiniTest::Expectations docs. http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html or, if that is still confusing, take a look at http://www.rubyinside.com/a-minitestspec-tutorial-elegant-spec-style-testing-that-comes-with-ruby-5354.html

Comment: haha I actually had those two pages open when you posted :) 
They don't really explain what each one does and I'm not super familiar with ruby so I don't know how to implement them without examples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing `shell_out` requires you to test against `stdout`

```
it "uses the correct timezone" do
  timezone_check = shell_out("date")
  timezone_check.stdout.must_match /UTC/
end
```

For more examples check out [Cookbook Integration Testing](http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2012/12/13/cookbook-integration-testing-with-real-examples/)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a proc and try using [`must_output`](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Expectations.html#method-i-must_output). The test would probably look like:

```
it "uses the correct timezone" do
    proc { timezone_check = shell_out("date") }.should_output /UTC/
end
```

Not entirely sure from the documentation that the `should_output` method will accept a pattern, but if you can write the test such that you know precisely the entire output expected, then you can simply test against the full expected string. E.g.

```
it "uses the correct timezone" do
    proc { timezone_check = shell_out("date") }.should_output("Fri Apr 19 12:33:13 CDT 2013")
end
```

Comment: I tried using the first example with must_output, but the shell_out seems to be producing nothing:


  `1) Failure:
test_0002_uses_the_correct_timezone(recipe::base::default) [/var/chef/minitest/base/default_test.rb:17]:
In stdout.
Expected: /UTC/
  Actual: ""`

Comment: and I can't use the second example because the output will be different every time.